# Managing multiple XMLs with some similarlity

Tags: xml

This might be a simple question but looks like probably I am perceiving in harder way. 
I need to design a framework to automate an application. It's a simple application in the sence it takes a request, process it, and send the response.
The request is something like a HTTP get command with some params. The response is an XML.

Based on the type of request and its param, the application prepares the response XML. Here are some examples

1) for requestA with param1, param2, the response XML is

```
<response type="B" ....>
    <subresponse .... />
</response>

<response type="C" ....>
    <subresponse .... />
</response>

<response type="D" ....>
    <subresponse .... />
</response>
```

2) for requestB with param1, param2, the response XML is

```
<response type="C" ....>
    <subresponse .... />
</response>
```

3) for requestC with param1, param2, the response XML is

```
<response type="C" ....>
    <subresponse .... />
</response>

<response type="B" ....>
    <subresponse .... />
</response>
```

As we can see, the response always follow the following patten.

1) The root xml tag is always output

2) Children of root have tag with name response.

3) Children can be discriminated by type attribute (A, B, C etc).

For automation, the major verification which we includes is the

a) verification of these XMLs

b) verification of contents

I am suggestin to do

i) XML validation against XSD for the verification of a)

ii) use of xPath to verify the contents b)

We have 50 such response type and based on the request, it will be sent to the client.

Please let me know if there is any other better so that I can efficiently manage this framework to adopt future changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validating the XML and then checking its contents using Xpath sound like reasonable approaches to checking XML. Regarding the latter, you could feed the XML into an appropriate XSLT stylesheet to check for non-conforming or unexpected structures and return meaningful errors of your choosing - or indeed correct common errors in XSLT and send the modified XML output to the client instead. Beyond that, it would be helpful to know what tools you're using, but I hope that answers your question about the approach you're considering.

Comment: Thanks, XSLT will be very much helpful here.